# JSTL - Modulus returning an exception - Caused by (#2):java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In my code below, it is returning a exception which is coming from the 3rd column. Is there a better way to write this logic to prevent an exception from happening? this is the exception that is occurring: Caused by (#2):java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Here is the code that maybe causing the problem: So all the customers are showing a number greater than "0" so the first statement is used. There are some cases where there are customers that are in the otherwise statement which is coming back as "0". So with a modulus you can't divide a number by "0" so an exception is thrown. What would be a better way to write this statement?

```
<c:choose>
       <c:when test="${total%columns != 0}">
           <c:set var="columnL" value="${total/columns + 1}"/>
           <c:set var="columnL" value="${fn:substringBefore(columnL, '.')}"/>
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
           <c:set var="columnL" value="${total/columns}"/>
           <c:set var="columnL" value="${fn:substringBefore(columnL, '.')}"/>
       </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
```

DEBUG added per request: 
1. ${Total%columns != 0}
2. ${Total/columns + 1}
3. ${Total/columns}

Added debug and 1 section is coming back as:
1. true,
2. 11.333333333333334,
3. 10.333333333333334

and another section is back as :(This is what is causing the issue)
1. false,
2. 9.0,
3. 8.0

As you notice looks like float numbers are being generated between the two which is causing an exception.

This is an overview of the full code.

```
<dsp:page>

   <c:set var="total" value="${fn:length(customers)}"/>
   <c:set var="columns" value="3"/>
   <c:set var="cCount" value="1"/>
   <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${total%columns != 0}">
           <c:set var="columnL" value="${total/columns + 1}"/>
           <c:set var="columnL" value="${fn:substringBefore(columnL, '.')}"/>
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
           <c:set var="columnL" value="${total/columns}"/>
           <c:set var="columnL" value="${fn:substringBefore(columnL, '.')}"/>
       </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>

   <c:forEach begin="1" end="${columns}" var="cCount" varStatus="status">
   <c:set var="begin" value="${(cCount -1) * columnL}"/>
   <c:choose>
       <c:when test="cCount == columns">
           <c:set var="end" value="${total - 1}"/>
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
           <c:set var="end" value="${(cCount) * columnL - 1}"/>
       </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
       <div id="dColumn${cCount}" class="dCol">
       <c:set var="cCount" value="${cCount+1}"/>
       <c:forEach items="${customers}" begin="${begin}" end="${end}" var="customer"    varStatus="status">
       <div class="link">
               <nm:a href="${customer.templateURL}">
                   <dsp:param name="param1" value="${customer.id}" />
                   <dsp:param name="param2" value="${customer.parentId}" />
                   <dsp:param name="param3" value="${customer.masterId}" />

               </nm:a>
           </div>
       </c:forEach>
       </div>
   </c:forEach>
   </dsp:page>
```

Comment: What exactly is the '3rd column', which line? What exception is thrown?

Comment: Please do not post the exception in a comment, instead update the question itself.

Comment: Please post only the specific code causing the problem; if we don't know where to look it makes it much more difficult to help. Code and exceptions in comments is difficult to read; just edit the question.

Comment: Editions made per Dave and home's request.

Comment: This suggests that `${column}` is `0`, but that's impossible as you've a `<c:set>` on it with a value of `3`. Is there something more into the real code? E.g. includes/tagfiles, etc? To debug, print `${column}` at the point where `<c:choose>` runs.

Comment: In the debug information you've added, the results of the divisions are `11.33`, `10.33`, `9.0` and `8.0`. So there is no division by zero issue here, it's somewhere else.